# jQuery .find need to ensure that both requirements are met before proceeding using tab through

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I'm trying to tab between input fields and select fields in a sliding form. However, with the code that I have it skips over the last input field on the current section of the form or the last select field on the current section of the form, regardless of whether there is a select or input field respectively afterwards. I need the tab to make sure that there are no select fields after the last input field and vice versa. This is the code I have so far:

```
$(this).find('input:last,select:last').bind('keydown',function(e){
```

But I need to to function more like this:

```
$(this).find('input:last && select:last').bind('keydown',function(e){
```

But the above code is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: @will The selected answer works for what I was needing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `:last` selector, you need to use the `.last()` method:

```
$(this).find('input, select').last().bind('keydown',function(e){
```

Reference for learning: [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

Comment: @N +1 for the reference. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following correctly, perhaps jQuery's [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) rather than each separately will work?

```
$(this).find(':input:last').bind('keydown', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.add()` method instead.

```
var $lastInput = $(this).find('input:last');
$lastInput.add($(this).find('select:last').bind('keydown', function(e) {
```